# When we talk about an event, should we use "It is" or "This is"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

When we talk about an event, which expression is more correct: "this is" or "it is"? Is there any difference in their meaning?

- Please, don't ask me about Jane again. This is completely redundant.
- Please, don't ask me about Jane again. It is completely redundant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [it VS. this Vs. that.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/159475/it-vs-this-vs-that) Also [What is difference between 'it' and 'this'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24981/) and [“It” vs. “that”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17255/it-vs-that) and [Using of “that” with the meaning of “this” or “it” at the beginning of a sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/157114/), among others. So far as ***I'm*** concerned, all of ***it, this, that*** are fine in the cited context, and ***mean exactly the same thing***.

Comment: (What's ***not*** "fine" is ***one another time***, which should be ***again***.)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica The accepted answer from the first link says that both "This is beautiful" and "It is beautiful" are equally valid options. So it seems this is just a matter of style?

Comment: If you're referring to the answer posted by "user6951", I'd take that with a pinch of salt. That user is clearly not a native Anglophone - which doesn't automatically mean the answer is "suspect", but I certainly think you should have a good look at answers in my other links above. Specifically, [this answer by Judicious Allure](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/159483/126) (aloso non-native Anglophone, as it happens! :) which covers at least *some* subtle contexts where the choice is a bit more than just a matter of "style".

Comment: My fault: it was the second link, not the first one. I'm not ready to mark this question as a duplicate right now, but yes, Judicious Allure's answer provides some help.